# Subprocedure call in VHDL

Tags: hardware, vhdl

I have two nested procedures, where the "main" procedure
makes use of "subproc" to accumulates a result in variables
t0 and t1, which is then returned at the end. This should all
be computed in one clock cycle, and the circuit more or less
just consists of simple logic gates (xor, or, and). When I try
to describe the circuit as below I get the following error:

```
Acutal (variable t0) for formal "a" is not a signal
```

That makes sense as the subprocure requires signals as input,
but I wanna pass it a variable during the main procedure. Is
there a simple way to circumvent this problem with casting for
example?

Thanks

```
procedure subproc
(
  signal a : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  signal b : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  signal c : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  signal d : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);    
  signal e : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  signal f : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)    
)
is
  variable x : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  variable y : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);    
begin

  x := (others => '0');
  y := (others => '0');

  for i in 0 to 31 loop
      x(i) := (a(i) xor b(i)) and (c(i) xor d(i));
      y(i) := (a(i) xor b(i)) or ((d(i) xor c(i)) xor b(i));
  end loop;

  e <= x(31 downto 0);
  f <= y(31 downto 0);

end;

procedure main
(
  signal a : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  signal b : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  signal r : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
)
is
  variable res : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  variable t0, t1 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  constant c : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := X"fedcba90";
  constant d : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := X"7654321f";       
begin

  t0 := (others => '0');
  t1 := (others => '0');

  for i in 0 to 31 loop
    if ( (c(i) = '0') && (d(i) = '1') ) then
       subproc( t0, t1, 
                a, b, t0, t1 );
    end if;              
  end loop;

  r <= t0;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, your "if" clause is written in C-style. You want to say:

```
if (c(i) = '0') and (d(i) = '1') then
```

But the problem really is that you describe the procedure as taking SIGNALs as arguments. If you want the results to be assigned to variables, you need to declare a different procedure signature:

```
procedure subproc (
signal a : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal b : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal c : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal d : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
variable e : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
variable f : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0))
```

But then, you also need to change all assignments to `e` and `f`, so that they are variable assignments:

```
e := x(31 downto 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just define the subproc parameters as variables instead of signals?